# Does ranked premade 5v5 MMR affect your 5v5 normal premade matchmaking?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've wondered if my 5v5 Ranked team MMR affects my 5v5 premade normal matchmaking.

Since soloqueue MMR influences the matchmaking of soloqueue normal games (i'm currently G1 and i always play vs G2 - P3 in normal and ranked games when i'm soloqueue), would it be possible that the team Ranked mmr also affect your normal games if you are 5 premades?

I mean if you are playing with 4 of your friends the enemy team will also have 5 premades. And it would be kinda unfair (although it's almost impossible) if a team that only consists of silver players but has a 5s ranked rating of like plat/diamond plays vs 5 other silver players.

Comment: ranked solo que doesnt affect normal solo que MMR. just as ranked team games dont affect normal team games.

Comment: Well i think soloqueue mmr does affect your solo normal games... I can't explain why i was playing vs silver and bronze when i was silver and bronze and now i play vs gold and plat... also pro players always play vs diamond plat when they play normals. You can look that up in lolking

Comment: That could be simply be because as you do better in ranked you're also doing better in normal meaning your MMR for both would be about the same.

Comment: @Jutschge its because your as skilled as you are in ranked as you are in normal. and unless you screw around in every normal game you will play against players your skill level.

Comment: I have many friends near a platinum level, but we get matched nearly always vs. unranked-silver level players.  (Usually 1bronze, 2gold, 2plat/diamond). Don't know specifics though.

Comment: basically what Paralytic said.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

Ranked MMR and normal MMR are definitely not synchronized.

You can see it when mostly any LoL pro (or anyone who improved in rankeds since last normal game) plays normals - they stomp hard, because their normal MMR is much lower than their more accurate assessment of their skill - their ranked MMR. If in such game their enemy team has ranked players, their ranks would reflect that unless they are in similar position (i.e. improved since last normal game) - their ranks would be much lower than that of said pro/high-elo player.

*Kinda related: Solo queue MMR does not affect Team MMR in no way way; besides maybe placement matches.
There are ways to test this hypothesis in a way - see http://op.gg/ for soloq and ranked team MMR or if you don't trust it's algorithms, just find a team with ranking severely below individual rankings (due to lack of communication etc), which is pretty common in lower divisions (higher up discrepancy is a bit less, by my observations)*

**Sources:**

- followed high-elo/pro NA/EUW/KR scene for several years
- saw effects of this in action as described above
- was interested in MMR innerworkings myself
- currently can not find Riot's information regarding this but remember reading it
- some minimal research shows that it is common knowledge.

Comment: Could you provide some source or explanation from where you have this information please?

Comment: @Lerkes, I fixed answer and provided what sources I have behind it